# How to access variables inside 'onMounted' lifecycle hook

Tags: vue-component, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I'm trying to use the ScrollY property to conditionally render the main menu in my app.

The changeCss function is working, and I get 'true' and 'false' from the console log when the scroll goes beyond 500px, but the v-if is not working.

Is there a way I can access this appear variable outside the onMounted() function to make the v-if work? I don't have access to 'this' as I'm using composition API with

This is my script:

```
<script setup lang="ts">

import { onMounted, ref } from 'vue';
import { RouterView } from "vue-router";
import Menu from "./components/menu.vue";

let appear: Boolean = true

onMounted(() => {

  function changeCss() {
    var bodyElement = document.querySelector("body");
    var navElement = document.querySelector("nav");
    scrollY > 500 ? appear = false : appear = true;
    scrollY > 500 ? console.log(appear) : console.log(appear);
  }
  window.addEventListener("scroll", changeCss, false);
})

</script>
```

And this is my template:

```
<template >
  <div class="app">

    <div v-if="appear">
      <Menu></Menu>
    </div>

    <div class="router_view">
      <RouterView />
    </div>

    <div>
      <!-- footer -->
    </div>

  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: declare your variables outside of your onMounted function.  now you have access to them.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ref() to make 'appear' variable 'reactive' (which means that template should 'react' on variable changes)

Disadvantage is that you have to read/write variable via '.value' property.

Something like that

```
<script setup lang="ts">
....
let appear = ref(true);
....
onMounted(() => {

  function changeCss() {
....
     apppear.value = false;
....    
  }
  window.addEventListener("scroll", changeCss, false);
})

</script>
```